# Send middle click when double right click is detected with Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

Hey my middle click button is kinda dead so I'm looking for a solution using Autohotkey.

What I want to do is send a middle click whenever I double right click, but I haven't been able to find a reliable solution so far.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe not the most elegant way, but you could try this:
Modyfied from: http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/16321-map-a-double-left-mouse-click-to-a-single-key/

```
$RButton::
if clicks > 0
   clicks++
else
{
   clicks := 1
   SetTimer, ClickWait, 400
}
return

ClickWait:
SetTimer, ClickWait, off
if clicks = 1
{
   Click, Right
}
else
{
   Click, Middle
}
clicks := 0
return
```

When you don't mind having the Right-Click menu appear, you can use this code, which sends the Right-Click straight through and corrects it later.

```
~RButton::
if (A_PriorHotkey <> "~RButton" OR A_TimeSincePriorHotkey > 600)
    Return ; No double click, so stop!
Sleep, 100
Send, {Esc}
Sleep, 100
Click, Middle
return
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it will delay the response of the single right click. I don't mind sending a right click I think, as long as the second will be a middle click

Comment: In that case you will always get the Right-Click menu on your screen, which you will have to undo with escape. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yeah that won't be a problem, what do I need to change to do this?

Comment: Just added the alternative code!